# all php pages give Internal Server Error

Tags: php, .htaccess

Since it's a friday, I can't ask my host about this, but apparently, all the .php pages on my websites are giving out the "Internal Server Error"... this started just now, I was not on my admin cp, I did 0 changes to my website today, in fact, I changed nothing for about a week now.

I host a few forums and got alerted by some users just now who were browsing and suddenly this happens.

The website in question:
cudamine.com

The error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal
>   error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server
>   administrator, xxx@email.com and
>   inform them of the time the error
>   occurred, and anything you might have
>   done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may
>   be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error
>   was encountered while trying to use an
>   ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I use cPanel X.

Should I be worried about this? Some sort of attack or something? All HTML pages work fine, it's just .php that seems to have this issue, is this a problem on my hosts end, or can I do anything about this before monday? Thanks guys, and sorry if this is the wrong place to ask. It's just that I don't want to have no site for the whole weekend...

After reading up on the web about similar situations, I found some info on the .htaccess file, I found the file and this is what's in it:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cudamine.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.cudamine.com$
RewriteRule ^santa\-maria\/forum\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/cudamine\.com\/santa\-maria\/\?page_id\=7\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Those two RewriteCond are 2 of my links that use php... I tried deleting this file, nothing changed though.

Comment: check `error_log` file which is in the same directory of your script(s).

Comment: sorry, i'm not very aware on this server stuff, i have all my files under public_html, can't seem to find any error_log file here...

Comment: Does your host have access logs and error logs available? The 503 page itself isn't very informative, but the actual logs will show more detail about what exactly is going on. We can't debug it based on the information you've supplied.

Comment: I do have an Access log folder with some files in there (my domain and subdomains), as for the error log, there is an error log feature on cPanel, it's full of repeating errors such as:

Comment: [Sat Nov 27 00:42:20 2010] [error] [client 66.249.66.39] File does not exist: /home/jdlf/public_html/500.shtml
[Sat Nov 27 00:42:04 2010] [error] [client 212.140.112.81] File does not exist: /home/jdlf/public_html/santa-maria/500.shtml
[Sat Nov 27 00:41:21 2010] [error] [client 212.140.112.81] File does not exist: /home/jdlf/public_html/santa-maria/404.shtml

Comment: @joao Those are the 404 errors for the missing error documents. You need to find the ones that start with "Internal Server Error"

Comment: Find stuff that involves php, like a fatal error, or such.

Comment: There are no errors besides "File does not exist", it only shows the last 300 errors, and it seems to update every minute with new erros... might be why I can't see what you're mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely check the error log (should be available in CPanel).

One common occurrence I see is when a host enables SuPHP (suexec for PHP scripts) and you have group writable scripts or directories containing scripts.

If your error log shows anything like "Apache SoftException", then this is the most likely cause. You need to change the filesystem permissions on your scripts and directories to remove the group "write" bit.

Another possible cause is your host has disabled `mod_rewrite` or removed the appropriate [overrides](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Override) (FileInfo) to use the `Rewrite*` directives.

Comment: The error log feature doesn't give me that error, all I get is repeating errors of "File does not exist" for pages like:

Comment: /home/jdlf/public_html/404.shtml / /home/jdlf/public_html/500.shtml

Answer (score 0):

PHP may be writing its error log elsewhere than the standard Apache error_log. You can retrieve the log's location with `ini_get('error_log')`. If the value's something other than "syslog", PHP is writing its errors to a file of the same name.

Comment: Where should I type that "ini_get('error_log')" info? Sorry, I just have no knowledge on this type of stuff...

Comment: Try it from a command line php script, since it's unlike it would work in a web-based one.